# A Dedekind Domain if and only if localizations at all nonzero primes are DVRs

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I am trying to understand a part of a proof given by Neukirch in his Algebraic Number Theory text. The highlighted part below is what I'm confused by.[image]

In particular, why do we choose $\pi\in\mathfrak{m}-\mathfrak{m}^2$, and not just any nonzero element of $\mathfrak{m}$? Also, why does $\mathfrak{m}^n=(\pi^n)$ imply that $\mathcal{O}_p$ is a PID? Couldn't there be an ideal of $\mathcal{O}$ that isn't necessarily a power of $\mathfrak{m}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We choose $\pi\in \mathfrak{m}\setminus \mathfrak{m}^2$ because this implies $\mathfrak{m}=(\pi)$. To see this, factor $(\pi)$ into non-zero prime ideals (possible since we are in a Dedekind domain). Since $\mathfrak{m}$ is the only non-zero prime ideal we necessarily have $(\pi)=\mathfrak{m}^n$ for some $n\geq 0$. As $\pi\in \mathfrak{m}$ we have $n\geq 1$ and since $\pi\notin\mathfrak{m}^2$ we also have $n<2$, hence $n=1$, i.e. $(\pi)=\mathfrak{m}$. If we wouldn't require $\pi\notin\mathfrak{m}^2$, we might have $(\pi)=\mathfrak{m}^n$ with $n>1$ which is not what we want.
By the same argument we see that any non-zero ideal of $\mathcal{O}_P$ is a product of primes and hence a power of $\mathfrak{m}$, therefore principal (actually for this we don't really need the Dedekind-property anymore: any noetherian local domain whose maximal ideal is principal is already principal ideal domain)